# Access linux-hosted ASP.NET Core 2.x webapp (without nginx)

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

My ASP.NET Core 2.1 webapp works perfectly on my dev setup. Now I want to test it in production.

The production server is Ubuntu 18. I followed [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx). I don't want to setup nginx yet, just do some quick tests, and the instructions say:

> "Either configuration—with or without a reverse proxy server—is a valid and supported hosting configuration for ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later apps".

So I built and published my project: `dotnet publish --configuration Release`. 
Then on the server:

- install the dotnet runtime
- copied files to server (`/var/www/myapp`)
- opened ports: `sudo uwf allow 5000/tcp 80/tcp`
- run `dotnet MyApp.dll` (also tried `sudo dotnet MyApp.dll`)

It runs without errors/warnings, and says it's listening on `http://localhost:5000`.

On my local machine I tried `http://serveripaddress` (and `http://serveripaddress:5000`) but get nothing ("can't connect"). I can access that server with ssh, sftp, etc - only http isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. I needed to use:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:5000" sudo dotnet MyApp.dll
```

Then it logs `Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000`. And I can access that from a remote client.

Comment: where exactly are you entering this "command"? are you sure `sudo` is correct?

Comment: Sorry but I don't remember - that was a long time ago, and the sdk has been upgraded since then. However I'm sure it's a typo and the sudo should come after the environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

the host default bind is 127.0.0.1 , so you can only access the app locally. if you want to access it from Network, please add `--urls` parameter. for example :

for development, you can run:

```
dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

and for deployed project, you can run:

```
dotnet MyApp.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

The dotnet core sdk I use is version 2.1.400.

Comment: That doesn't work on `2.1` - I think they removed that option. See my answer.

Comment: may be they adjust the parameter name, I will try it , there should be a parameter can change the binding address.

Comment: My way works, but I prefer your way - I hope there is a new parameter for this.

Comment: @lonix , I have tried, it works, please see my edited answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I ran `dotnet --info` which shows host is version `2.1.3`. I remember reading somewhere that `urls` is no longer supported. I'm not sure why it works for you but not me. Thanks anyway.